# solr query for not equal to text value and number greater than 0

Tags: solr, solrj

I have solr documents with two fields, one is a string and one is an integer.  Both fields are allowed to be null.  I am attempting to write a query that will eliminate documents with the following properties:

textField = "badValue" AND (numberField is null OR numberField = 0)

I added the following fq:

```
((NOT textField=badValue) OR numberField=[1 TO *])
```

This does not seem to have worked properly, because I am getting a document with textField = badValue and numberField = 0.  What did I do wrong with my fq?

The full query response header, containing the parsed query is:

"responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 245,
    "params": {
      "q": "(numi) AND (solr_specs:[* TO *] OR full_description:[* TO *])",
      "defType": "edismax",
      "bf": "log(sum(popularity,1))",
      "indent": "true",
      "qf": "categories^3.0 manufacturer^1.0 sku^0.2 split_sku^0.2 upc^1.0 invoice_description^2.6 full_description solr_specs^0.8 solr_spec_values^1.7 legacyid legacy_altcode id",
      "fl": "distributor_status,QOH_estimate,id,score",
      "start": "0",
      "fq": "((*:* NOT distributor_status=VENDORDISC) OR QOH_estimate=[1 TO *])",
      "sort": "score desc,id desc",
      "rows": "20",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1441220051438"
    }
  }

QOH_estimate is numberField and distributor_status is textField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following in your `fq` parameter: `((*:* NOT textField:badValue) OR numberField:[1 TO *])`.

`((*:* NOT distributor_status:VENDORDISC) OR QOH_estimate:[1 TO *])`

Here you first selecting the documents which are not containing `textField:badValue` and `OR`ing with documents coming from `numberField:[1 TO *]` condition.

Comment: I tried using your specified fq parameter, and got the same results with and without the filter.  Just as was the case with my initial guess as to how to accomplish this, the query seems to allow a document with textField = badValue and numberField = 0.

Comment: Can you provide the exact query you are using?

Comment: I modified the question to include the response header, which contains a parsed copy of the query.

Comment: looks like you are putting this in `qf` parameter not in `fq` parameter. `fq` stands for Filter Query.

Comment: Oops I think I made a mistake copying, I fixed it and the problem is still there.

Comment: updated the answer. use `:` instead of `=` in the filter query parameter.